# Encrypting data on Windows Phone 7.1 (Mango)

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, encryption, windows-phone-7.1

How can I encrypt data in `IsolatedStorage` using a X.509 certificate provided by my Azure Service? I can't find any documentation on MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

you can find some discussion concerning this problem (X.509) [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/windowsphone7series/thread/3061aaf8-f644-4fc0-887e-19e22c2fe021)